# CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve not being able resolve 'some' assemblies

Tags: c#, assembly-resolution

After finding the answer my last question on assembly resolving ( [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve asking for a <AppName>.resources assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368201/appdomain-currentdomain-assemblyresolve-asking-for-a-appname-resources-assembly) ) now i'm able to embed references assemblies on my program except that this does not work some references somehow.

First of all i setup my assembly resolver at the very first entrance of my Program.cs

```
    // attach our embedded assembly loader.
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyManager.Instance.Resolver;
```

Here's my actual resolver;

```
public Assembly Resolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    AssemblyName askedAssembly = new AssemblyName(args.Name);

    lock (this)
    {
        Assembly assembly;

        string resourceName = string.Format("Assets.Assemblies.{0}.dll", askedAssembly.Name);
        using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                LogManager.Instance.Write(LogMessageTypes.Fatal, string.Format("Can not resolve asked assembly: {0}", askedAssembly.Name));
                MessageBox.Show(i18n.CanNotLoadRequiredAssembliesMessage, i18n.CanNotLoadRequiredAssembliesTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            byte[] assemblyData = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
            assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
        }

        LogManager.Instance.Write(LogMessageTypes.Trace, "Loaded embedded assembly: " + askedAssembly.Name);

        return assembly;
    }
}
```

Now my program references these libraries assemblies.

- Esent.Collections.dll
- Esent.Interop.dll
- HtmlAgilityPack.dll
- Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll
- System.Windows.Forms.Calendar.dll
- AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects
- Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects
- **irrKlang.NET4.dll**
- **ikpMP3.dll**
- **Nini.dll (SOLVED)**

With my resolver above; i can embed Esent.Collections, Esent.Interop, HtmlAgilityPack, Ionic.Zip.Reduced,System.Windows.Forms.Calendar,AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects,Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects and resolve those on run-time.

The problem arrives with irrKlang.NET.4, Nini and ShockwaveFlash assemblies in which if i try to embed these assemblies and try to resolve them at runtime i'm having problems.

For irrKlang i can understand the problem as irrKlang.NET4 assembly references unmanaged ikpMP3.dll which i can't find on it's own.

For the Nini.dll, actually i can embed this assembly and using VS debug/release configurations runned it just works okay but when i startup the program on my own from the explorer, the program just refuses to startup (with no errors or any bit of info).

Any help appreciated.

**Update**
Now, thanks Marc Gravell's answer i can load the Nini.dll.

For the irrKlang part, as irrKlang.NET4.dll is a managed assembly which requires ikpMp3.dll -- an unmanaged one --, if i try to resolve irrKlang.NET4.dll on run-time it can access its required dependency ikpMp3. Is there work-around for this?

Comment: Do you use any of the types from the `Main` method? it must be able to fully JIT `Main` to start the app...

Comment: Nini.dll is accessed from Main method actually. I'll give it a try and move it away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common problem here is to use the types before you have chance to register the assembly-resolve event. In particular, note that the system must be able to JIT a method before it can *start* running a method - including `Main()`.

So if your entry-point (`Main()`) does the event hooking **and also** talks to the types in question, it will attempt to resolve the types (for JIT) **before** or has chance to subscribe.

Do the minimum in main; move the "real" code to another method, that is only invoked once the event is definitely subscribed.

For example:

```
static void Main() {
    SubscribeAssemblyResolver();
    ExecuteApplication();
}
```

In extreme cases you may even need to use MethodImplAttribute to disable inlining of the methods above.

Comment: Yes, thanks moving the calls to Nini assembly from Main() done the magic, JIT can now load the program and further Nini.dll references are just correctly resolved using my supplied resolver.