# Outlook Add-In loads but is not showing

Tags: outlook, loading, add-in

My solution consists of 2 add-ins: 1 for Outlook and one for Word. They load and work perfectly in Debug mode. Both based on Add-In Express library. Both are registered correctly during install, for example: adxregistrator.exe /install=MyOutlookAddIn.dll /privileges=admin
The installer works fine and everything completes successfully. When I open Outlook I can see the MyOutlookAddIn is in the list of Active Add-Ins. However, my custom Ribbon Tab is not showing at all.

When I run Fusion Log Viewer I see the following message. It is very strange because I do not have any assemblies with the name MyOutlookAddIn.resources.DLL and none either generated automatically...I googled all day long but at no avail. I can't find any reason for these error messages (assuming that the problem come out from it). Any clues of pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
===============
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/17/2013 @ 7:54:46 PM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\OUTLOOK.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = ZZZ-PC\ZZZ
LOG: DisplayName = MyOutlookAddIn.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en,     PublicKeyToken=62b2da92ff61da99
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Leon/AppData/Roaming/My/MyOfficeAddIn/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : MyOutlookAddIn, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=62b2da92ff61da99.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from          C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: MyOutlookAddIn.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en,         PublicKeyToken=62b2da92ff61da99
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL     file:///C:/Users/Leon/AppData/Roaming/My/MyOfficeAddIn/en/MyOutlookAddIn.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL     file:///C:/Users/Leon/AppData/Roaming/My/MyOfficeAddIn/en/MyOutlookAddIn.resources/MyOutlookAddIn.resources.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Leon/AppData/Roaming/My/MyOfficeAddIn/en/MyOutlookAddIn.resources.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL   file:///C:/Users/Leon/AppData/Roaming/My/MyOfficeAddIn/en/MyOutlookAddIn.resources/MyOutlookAddIn.resources.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.
```

=============================

Apparently I resolved the error messages in the Fusion Log by using solution proposed here:
[AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve asking for a <AppName>.resources assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368201/appdomain-currentdomain-assemblyresolve-asking-for-a-appname-resources-assembl?rq=1)

However it did not resolve my main problem that my Outlook Add-In does not show in Outlook despite that it is shown as loaded...Any other tools I can use to find where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the installer doesn't include the Localized Resources project output. And check if there're problem in the adxloader.log file.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Add-in Express do you use? Please check if the 'Show add-in user interface errors' option is enabled in Outlook. If not, try to enable it and restart Outlook. Probably you will get any ribbon UI errors. You can also send a sample project to the support e-mail. I will test it on my PC.

Sergey Grischenko
Add-in Express team