# DevExpress - windows forms application1 has encountered a problem and needs to close?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I've playing around with DevExpress gauges. Works fine on my computer, yet when I build the .exe file and give it to someone, his computer shows "windows forms application1 has encountered a problem and needs to close".

Any ideas what might be causing it?
Thanks!

Comment: By the way that's a very generic error that normally (but not always) means there's a DLL missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a variety of reasons why this could be happening.

1) .NET framework isn't installed correctly or the version you developed the application does not match the end machine .NET version.

2) DevExpress puts the assemblies on your Global Assembly Cache. The application running on the end machine must a way to find these assemblies.

In this case you have 2 choices:

1. Place the DevExpress DLLs you are referencing in the same directory the application is running (recommended)
2. Install DevExpress / Copy the DLLs to GAC on the end machine

Comment: Thanks... yes is it possible to somehow keep everything packed in one .exe file?

Comment: @Rob, this is another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453755/how-to-embed-a-satellite-assembly-into-the-exe-file