# C# resource not embedded if contains language code in file name

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, embedded-resource

All files have same setting for Build Action : Embedded Resource

The files with language code in the file name are not embedded as resource.See the print screen from `ILSpy`. Only the file without language (for testing ) it's embedded.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: As Andrii Litvinov mentioned, resource are compiled in separated assemblies. Maybe this thread could help having resources in main assembly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952638/single-assembly-multi-language-windows-forms-deployment-ilmerge-and-satellite-a/1955060#1955060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those language-specific resources are compiled to separate assemblies which you can find under `bin/Debug/{lang}/{resources}.dll`.

Comment: Mean time I found out that too. Is there any way to disable that behavior and to have resources embedded in main assembly?

Comment: I am not aware of such possibility out of the box. There was similar question and Fody was suggested as a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663001/how-can-i-embed-c-sharp-assembly-resources-in-the-same-assembly.