# Running an EXE within my VB.net assembly

Tags: vb.net, .net-assembly

I have a file-translation library in the form of a Win32 EXE and a stub DLL that feeds parameters to it. I have written a lightweight (~500 lines) VB.net app that creates the file to be translated, then calls the DLL to launch the EXE. Unfortunately, this results in my EXE, their EXE, the DLL and another supporting file. I'd prefer to have a single file.

Following the basic idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798655/embedding-an-external-executable-inside-a-c-sharp-program) doesn't seem to help - I need to have all three files able to see each other, and it's not clear how to do this from those examples. I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453755/how-to-embed-a-satellite-assembly-into-the-exe-file), but again, this appears to be running an EXE that is "beside" the .net code, not embedded within it.

So, is there a way to run the EXE/DLL/supporting file "in situ"? Are the Assemblies ultimately a directory structure where I can run the EXE? And if so, how does one find/refer to these files?

Comment: You could probably do something something like add the .exe of the library to your project as an embedded resource.  This would cause it to always be copied to the /bin of your project when built.  AFAIK, it's not possible to 'embed' an executable into your project..

Comment: I did the "basic embed" already just so I don't forget to copy them over. Is there a way to direct them to be "beside" my app, rather than in a Resources subfolder?